CDC from BigQuery
Could you please tell if it is possible to capture CDC on a GCP BigQuery database in order to receive notifications for every INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE performed in BigQuery tables? If so, could you provide the documentation that describes how to do this? I know how to perform CDC to BigQuery, but I don't know if it is possible to perform CDC from BigQuery.

Backin April at Google's NEXT conference, a feature called "BigQuery continuous queries" was announced.  The video for it can be found here.  This feature continuously monitors one or more tables and when something "changes" in the table, an action is performed.  One of the first uses is for outbound CDC.  When something changes in the table, the corresponding changed row/details can be published to PubSub.
As of the time of this post (2024-06), I do not believe that the feature is generally available ... however, if you reach out to your Google Cloud sales rep, there is a private preview programme on-going where you can get early access to it.  I am not aware of when the formal general availability is scheduled.

Thank you for the answer! One more question - can I handle INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE events with BigQuery EventArc?

I watched the video you provided, and this feature looks simply amazing! At the moment, I have a few questions - can a large number of dfferent BigQuery continuous queries be run in parallel (for example 50k queries), and how will BigQuery handle this? Additionally, how are updates handled - does each BigQuery continuous query read all the data from the storage for every new event/update, or does it only read incrementally, as Epsio.io does, for example?

Howdy @alexanoid ... My understanding is that the feature is in private preview.  What that means is that support (including questions, its current function, the function it will have at GA and beyond) is being handled directly by the BigQuery product management team and BigQuery engineering.  Putting it another way, there isn't really ANY experience with it that anyone (except the above) can share.  There will be training and docs by GA.  In the meantime, I'd contact your Google account team and ask them for a briefing.  They should be able to schedule a call with you and engineering.
